# As return a record that contains several comma separated values php mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql

```
Table example:
id  - registro  - valor
1   - compras   - 1,2,6
2   - ventas    - 3,4
3   - deudas    - 5
4   - Something - 13,14,15,16,10
```

I have this table in the database. I want to do a query where I send only the number 3 and I bring register 2. In this example. It can be done. IN probe with and do not, I tried it with CONTAINS and neither does. I should do ... Help

Comment: `find_in_set` is your friend. But you should think about your db design. Storing values as csv is very bad db design

Comment: I'm not storing data as csv. only to convert an array to string using the comma as the separator. and that's it..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Jens says, you can use [the `FIND_IN_SET()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) for this purpose.

```
SELECT registro
  FROM tbl
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET('3', valor) > 0
```

And, like @Jens said, this is poor database design. Storing more than one value in a particular column of a row defeats many of the optimizations built into RDMS systems.

You'd be better off with two tables:

master

```
master_id - registro
 1        - compras
 2        - ventas
 3        - deudas
 4        - Something
```

detail (notice there's just one `valor` per row here)

```
master_id  - valor
  1        -  1
  1        -  2
  1        -  6
  2        -  3
  3        -  4
   etc.
```

Then you can use queries like this

```
  SELECT master.registro
    FROM detail
    JOIN master ON master.master_id = detail.master_id
   WHERE detail.valor = 3
```

Normalizing your tables like this may look like a lot of extra work. But if your application scales up, doing it this way will be tens of thousands of times faster. Seriously.